# Getting values out of AJAX response

Tags: javascript

I am getting response like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "958315db-ca46-4b32-ad89-f0564a2bfa37",
    "name": "XXXX",
    "device_count": 3,
    "gateway_count": 2,
    "longitude": -109.207929275995,
    "latitude": 33.1906871835467
  },
  {
    "id": "4485e5ee-ba30-4103-8f24-c710efed3929",
    "name": "YYYY",
    "device_count": 0,
    "gateway_count": 0,
    "longitude": null,
    "latitude": null
  }
]
```

How can I parse it in JavaScript and get two ids and names in an array? Sorry, I am new to JavaScript

Comment: `var ids = JSON.parse(response).map(e => e.id);`

Comment: @Tushar you might want to use ES5 syntax instead; it might be confusing if you don't know the shorthand syntax.

Comment: Actually, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object is the "canonical" answer.  However, the problem with both of those answers as they pretty much go "use `JSON.parse`" with no further information on how to access the results.

Comment: @Tushar 's answer only answers half the original question as it only gets the 'id's and not the 'name's.

Answer (score 2):

As you've the **string** representation of JSON. To convert it to JSON object, you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

To get the `id` field from each of the object in the array, you can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here shown using [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in ES6.

```
JSON.parse(response).map(e => ({
    id: e.id,
    name: e.name
}));
```

```js
var response = '[ { "id": "958315db-ca46-4b32-ad89-f0564a2bfa37", "name": "XXXX", "device_count": 3, "gateway_count": 2, "longitude": -109.207929275995, "latitude": 33.1906871835467 }, { "id": "4485e5ee-ba30-4103-8f24-c710efed3929", "name": "YYYY", "device_count": 0, "gateway_count": 0, "longitude": null, "latitude": null } ]';

var ids = JSON.parse(response).map(e => ({
    id: e.id,
    name: e.name
}));

console.log(ids);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ids, 0, 4) + '</pre>'; // For DEMO purpose
```

The same code can be written using anonymous function in ES5.

```
JSON.parse(response).map(function (obj) {
    return {
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name
    };
});
```

```js
var response = '[ { "id": "958315db-ca46-4b32-ad89-f0564a2bfa37", "name": "XXXX", "device_count": 3, "gateway_count": 2, "longitude": -109.207929275995, "latitude": 33.1906871835467 }, { "id": "4485e5ee-ba30-4103-8f24-c710efed3929", "name": "YYYY", "device_count": 0, "gateway_count": 0, "longitude": null, "latitude": null } ]';

var ids = JSON.parse(response).map(function (obj) {
    return {
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name
    };
});
console.log(ids);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ids, 0, 4) + '</pre>'; // For DEMO purpose
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are getting this json on data variable

```
 var data = [ { "id": "958315db-ca46-4b32-ad89-f0564a2bfa37", "name": "XXXX", "device_count": 3, "gateway_count": 2, "longitude": -109.207929275995, "latitude": 33.1906871835467 }, { "id": "4485e5ee-ba30-4103-8f24-c710efed3929", "name": "YYYY", "device_count": 0, "gateway_count": 0, "longitude": null, "latitude": null } ]
```

You can easily access the id as `data[0].id` of first element. `data.length` will give you the total number of objects so that you can iterate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse()` to turn the string into a "equivalent" JavaScript object.  More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);         // an array in your case
var ids = obj.map(e => e.id);
var names = obj.map(e => e.name);
```

The `.map()` calls are using the new "fat arrow" operator.  This nearly-equivalent syntax may be more familiar:

```
var ids = obj.map( function(e) { return e.id; } );
```

Info on the Array map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Info on [Fat] Arrow Functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions